# Book on atmosphere dynamics

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-circulation

I plan to study a good introductory book on atmospheric dynamics:
which one is more recommended? My background is a university degree in physics, but I'm new to meteorology.

- An Introduction to
  Dynamic Meteorology
  James R. Holton
- Fluid Dynamics of the
  Midlatitude Atmosphere
  Brian J. Hoskins
- Mid-Latitude Atmospheric
  Dynamics, A First Course
  Jonathan E. Martin

Comment: I can only comment on Holtons book as this is the only one I've been using a lot. I think it has a nice pace and if your vector calculus skills are still a bit in shape it's a pleasure reading it. A word of warning: there is a huge difference between editions 4 and 5 as 4 treats the dynamics in pressure coordinates, while 5 uses cartesian. I advise using edition 4 because pressure coordinates are more commonly used in dynamic meteorology. That said... I have ed. 5 in my shelf and for underetanding the concepts the difference is probably minor.

Comment: I thought, that pressure coordinates are a bit more sophisticated as an approach. Why was ist skipped in ed 5?

Comment: I'll check the foreword once I'm back home on Sunday. For now I can only guess that pressure as a vertical coordinate may seem abstract to a few at first. Pressure coordinates are in my opinion more sophisticated (as you said) as e.g. they allow you to compare the atmosphere at different locations more meaningful.

Comment: I agree with all Joscha said.  I'm nearing 20 years removed from dynamics courses, only experienced Holton, but the pace and detail seemed solid from what I remember.  Not sure you'll manage a full answer, as I would think the only ones well up to date on multiple texts to probably only be professors mainly, maybe a small group of nonteaching researchers... but unless you're lucky, may not be enough traffic here to get the true expert on it.  But huzzah on jumping into it!

Comment: Holton is good, don't know the others. However where Holton is severely lacking (as well as all other meteorology books I have seen so far) is a proper, proper derivation of the full equations of motions in spherical coordinates. Holton, as all others, uses a hand-wavy vector-pictorial approach to derive the curvature and Coriolis terms. I have yet to see a satisfying first-order derivation of those, akin to what one would expect to come out naturally of a general relativistic treatment of curvature and inertial frames.

Comment: @atmosphericprisonescape: I recently  did this type of derivation by only using geometric facts  and could derive the known set of equations in coordinates i,j,k. However,  it was a rather tedious and boring task. It is just rearranging terms of sin and cos oder a few pages without any physical content. The pictorial approach is in some way more physically, although I dislike it too.